# RabbitMQ/Spring: Will another exclusive consumer register itself, if the current exclusive deregisters?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, cloud-foundry

I have a spring application which runs in multiple instances on cloudfoundry.
These instances share a database. They have a `RabbitListener` configured like so:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${items.updated.queue}", exclusive = true)
```

The queue gets a message if a reimport of items from a certain source is required.

I only want one instance to perform the import. To my understanding this can be accomplished by the exclusive flag.

Now, what would happen if the current `exclusive consumer` crashes? 
Would another currently running instance register itself as the new `exclusive consumer`? Or does the registration only take place when the application starts up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, another consumer will be granted access.

Consumers will re-attempt to consume every `recoveryInterval` milliseconds (default 5000 - 5 seconds).

You can change this by setting the interval or a `recoveryBackoff` in the listener container.

Note that you will get a WARN log from the container about the failure and an INFO log from the connection factory that the channel was closed due to a failure.

You can either adjust the log levels to reduce these logs, or you can inject custom `ConditionalExceptionLogger` s into both the container and factory.

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#consumer-events).

> If a consumer fails because one if its queues is being used exclusively, by default, as well as publishing the event, a WARN log is issued. To change this logging behavior, provide a custom `ConditionalExceptionLogger` in the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`'s `exclusiveConsumerExceptionLogger` property. See also the section called “Logging Channel Close Events”.

Comment: we're implementing the `ConditionalExceptionLogger` to not log the error more than once. This way we don't mess with the recovery interval nor the backoff attempts and at the same time not pollute the logs with too many entries.